# Use value from form to render specific data from firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to render data from my Firebase Firestore DB after a user enters a control number from a form.

This is SingleQuery hook a.k.a. the listener to my Firestore DB

```
//Code to Query data from Database
function SingleQuery() {
  const [drivers, setDrivers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("drivers")
      .where("controlNumber", "==", {{CONTROL NUMBER FROM FORM}}) //get data according to control number
      .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
        const newDriver = snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
          return {
            // returns a new Object
            id: doc.id,
            ...doc.data()
          };
        });
        setDrivers(newDriver);
      });

    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, []);

  return drivers;
}
```

Code below generates what the user can see after entering the control number. the search box is under `<div className="searchBar">` and the result will be generated under `<div className="queryResults">`

```
export const violationQuery = () => {
  const drivers = SingleQuery();

  return (
    <Styles>
      <div className="violationQuery">
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <h4>Enter Control Number</h4>
        <div className="searchBar" class="input-group-sm">
          <form>
            <input
              type="text"
              className="form-control"
              aria-label="Small"
              aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm"
              placeholder="Control Number"
              id="controlNum"
            />
            <br />
            <input className="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit" />
          </form>
        </div>

        <div className="queryResults">
          <br />
          <h5>
            Showing results for <b>Insert Control Number</b>
          </h5>
          <br></br>
          <Container>
            <Row>
              <Col>
                <div id="results-list">
                  {drivers.map(driver => (
                    <ol key={driver.id}>
                      <li>
                        <b>Control Number</b>: {driver.controlNumber}
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <b>Date and Time</b>: {driver.dateAndTime}
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <b>Driver name</b>: {driver.name}
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <b>License Number</b>: {driver.licenseNumber}
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <b>Violations</b>: {driver.violations}
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <b>Location</b>: {driver.latitude}, {driver.longitude}
                      </li>
                    </ol>
                  ))}
                </div>
              </Col>
              <Col>
                <MapView2 />
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Container>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Styles>
  );
};
```

I'm sorry if the presentation of the question a bit messed up, hoping for some answers. Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking how to pass a parameter to a react hook (or utility function), in this case, from the form's `onSubmit` to the `SingleQuery` hook/function to return an array of `drivers`? Can you provide the entire `SingleQuery` function?

Comment: @DrewReese yes, pass from the forms `onSubmit` to `SingleQuery` and return it to `drivers` specifically in the `where()` method in `SingleQuery`

Comment: Can you provide the entire `SingleQuery` function?

Comment: @DrewReese that's the entire `SingleQuery` function. both `SingleQuery` and `violationQuery` are in the same file

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but the entire function/hook is not there, you included only up to the end of the `useEffect` hook. What does `SingleQuery` return?

Comment: @DrewReese my bad, updated the code already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to save `controlNumber` in state and pass it the SingleQuery hook. Add a check inside SingleQuery hook such that `controlNumber` should not be empty or null beore making an API call. And also add `controlNumber` in dependency array of useEffect.

```js
export const violationQuery = () => {
  const [inputControlNumber, setInputControlNumber] = useState("");
  const [controlNumber, setControlNumber] = useState("");

  const drivers = SingleQuery(controlNumber);

  function onSubmit(e) {
     setControlNumber(inputControlNumber);
       e.preventDefault();
  };

  return (
    <Styles>
      <div className="violationQuery">
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <h4>Enter Control Number</h4>
        <div className="searchBar" class="input-group-sm">// class attr won't work. Add it to className.
          <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
            <input
              type="text"
              className="form-control"
              aria-label="Small" 
              aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm"
              placeholder="Control Number"
              id="controlNum"   // do not use Id unless you have some special case to handle.
              value={inputControlNumber}
              onChange={(event) => setInputControlNumber(event.target.value);}
            />
            <br />
            <input className="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit" />
          </form>
        </div>

        <div className="queryResults">
          <br />
          <h5>
            Showing results for <b>Insert Control Number</b>
          </h5>
          <br></br>
          <Container>
            <Row>
              <Col>
                <div id="results-list">
                  {drivers.map(driver => (
                    <ol key={driver.id}>
                      <li>
                        <b>Control Number</b>: {driver.controlNumber}
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <b>Date and Time</b>: {driver.dateAndTime}
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <b>Driver name</b>: {driver.name}
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <b>License Number</b>: {driver.licenseNumber}
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <b>Violations</b>: {driver.violations}
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <b>Location</b>: {driver.latitude}, {driver.longitude}
                      </li>
                    </ol>
                  ))}
                </div>
              </Col>
              <Col>
                <MapView2 />
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Container>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Styles>
  );
};
```

```js
function SingleQuery(controlNumber) {
  const [drivers, setDrivers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("drivers")
      .where("controlNumber", "==", controlNumber) //get data according to control number
      .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
        const newDriver = snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
          return {
            // returns a new Object
            id: doc.id,
            ...doc.data()
          };
        });
        setDrivers(newDriver);
      });

    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, [controlNumber]);

  return drivers;
}
```

Comment: I added `controlNumber` in the dependency array at `useEffect`. I'm getting 2 errors saying that both `controlNumber` and `onSubmit` are undefined

Comment: Can you provide a sandbox link where we can take a look?

Comment: i will try. it might take me a while to set it up

Comment: Okay, just try replicating the issue. You can remove the rest of the code. I need to take a look at SingleQuery hook

Comment: Hello. Here it is [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-browser-0ht3u)

Comment: you forgot to add controlNumber as an argument in SingleQuery hook. Also, I change submit handler check my edit

Comment: Glad it helped. You can also add a check inside the callback of useEffect such that it does not make a call to firebase for empty controlNumber. Also you can read about useCallback too

Answer (score 0):

Hope I understood the question. Why not to make your SingleQuery function as a simple function with input parameter (user data) and violationQuery as functional component with const [drivers, setDrivers] = useState([]); and onSubmitFormHandler change your state by calling SingleQuery?